# Establish if a document satisifies a query (without actually performing the query) in ElasticSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a document (that I know is in the index), and a query. Is there a way of knowing if the document satisfies the query, without actually querying the index and looking into the results.

So for example, I'd like to know if the document

```
{ "price" : 30, "productID" : "1937" }
```

satisifes the query

```
{'query': {'bool': {
        'should': [{'bool': {
            'must': [{'term': {'price': 30}}, {'term': {'productID': '1937'}}]}},
            {'term': {'productID': '9947'}}]
    }}}
```

which is basically

```
productID      = 9947
OR (productID = 1937 AND price = 30 )
```

This is an easy case, but I need something for arbitrary queries.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to know the results of the query before executing it?

Comment: Sort of. I have a document and a query, and I want a function that returns True or False. I don't need all the other documents

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a direct way of doing this. You could either:

A) Issue a query, filtering by the document's ID using the `ids` query to avoid querying all of your documents:

```
{
    "ids" : {
        "type" : "my_type",
        "values" : ["1", "4", "100"]
    }
}
```

Example from: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html

B) Use ES's percolator to index the *query*, then query *by document*:

Index the query:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my-index/.percolator/1' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "message" : "bonsai tree"
        }
    }
}'
```

Query by document:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my-index/my-type/_percolate' -d '{
    "doc" : {
        "message" : "A new bonsai tree in the office"
    }
}'
```

Response:

```
{
    "took" : 19,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 5,
        "successful" : 5,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "total" : 1,
    "matches" : [ 
        {
          "_index" : "my-index",
          "_id" : "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Examples from: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html

If the response has your query's ID, then your query applies to the document. The upside to this approach is that you can run it multiple times for different documents.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the document's ID, you can use the "explain" api. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html

So assuming your documents id is `1234abc` you can do the following

```
curl -XGET 'your_es_server:9200/your_index/your_mapping/1234abc/_explain' -d '{'query': {'bool': {
    'should': [{'bool': {
        'must': [{'term': {'price': 30}}, {'term': {'productID': '1937'}}]}},
        {'term': {'productID': '9947'}}]
}}}'
```

And this should return something like this.

```
    {
  "_index": "your_index",
  "_type": "your_mapping",
  "_id": "1234abc",
  "matched": true,
  "explanation": {
    "value": 0.06100826,
    "description": "sum of:",
    "details": [.........
....
...
...
```

You can just check if the `matched` variable in the above response is true or not.